# Escape a single quote sign in highcharts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm working on a Rails app and have a serie name "Helen's book" which is shown on the chart as Helen`&#39;`s book.

I tried to use gsub method in the controller but it didn't work out:

```
@results[:data].each{|result| x[:result].gsub("'", "\\\\'")}
```

**How to achieve a properly shown single quote sign?**

Comment: Not sure what you need. Replace any `'`  with the `&#39;` entity?

Comment: I need to properly show a `'`, not `&#39;` on the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is 2016. Use UTF-8 proper typographic apostrophe

```
@results[:data].each do |result|
  x[:result].gsub(/(?<=\W)['"]/, "‘")
            .gsub(/['"](?=\W)/, "’")
            .gsub("'", "’")
end

#⇒ Helen’s book
#⇒ Book ‘Adventures’
```

Comment: What if I would have `Book 'Adventures'`? It is not good to use apostrophe here too

Comment: Please see an update. This covers 99% properly and puts apostrophe on the rest 1%. It’s still better than using single typewriter quotes.